# jquery data attribute multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I have an issue with using multiple values in a data tag, and applying a filter based on the id of this. because its showing multiple ids in the data tag it wont show both ids.

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/rWhVN/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#content').removeClass('nojs');
            $('.row').not('#q1').hide();
            $('select').on('change', function () {
                var question = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
                var answerID = $(this).children('option:selected').attr('id');
                var loadQuestion = $(this).children('option:selected').data('load');
                $('#' + question).addClass('answered');
                $('.row').not('.answered').hide();
                $('#' + loadQuestion).fadeIn();
                console.log(loadQuestion);
            });
        });
    </script>

<option id="q1a1" data-load="q2, q8">Answer 1</option>
```

Question one answer one should show question two and question eight.

Not sure how you split this out, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#' + loadQuestion)` will be `$('#q2, q8')`, which will not be the seletor for `#q2` and `#q8`.

You could do `data-load="#q2, #q8"`, and then just do `$(loadQuestion)`.

***[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWhVN/1/)***.

And if you can't change the `data-load` attribute, then you could do with:

```
$($.map(loadQuestion.split(/ *, */), function(el) {return '#'+el;}).join(',')).fadeIn();
```

Comment: thats really helpful, I haven't looked at the map feature yet so thanks very much for your help